# Validar que un método no se registre NULO en una BD

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, itextsharp, textbox

Que tal estoy usando windows forms .net framework4.2, conectado a base de datos... tengo el siguiente método; este método contiene CINCO checkbox donde cada uno devuelve un valor para que se guarde en una tabla de la base de datos.
'NOMBRE DEL METODO: CheckCondicion'.

```
public String CheckCondicion() 
{ 
if (checkBox14.Checked == true) 
return "Funcionando correctamente"; 
} 
else if (checkBox15.Checked == true) 
{ 
return "Funcionando Parcialmente"; 
} 
else if (checkBox16.Checked == true) 
{ 
return "Fuera de servicio"; 
} 
else if (checkBox17.Checked == true) 
{ 
return "Baja equipo"; 
} 
else if (checkBox18.Checked == true) 
{ 
return "Otro"; 
} 
else 
{ 
return null; 
} 
}
```

Al registrar en la base de datos para validación que el USUARIO no deje vacía esta parte del form, quiero poner la validación en el siguiente metodo:

```
private bool checarValidez() 
{ 
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_nombre.Text)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("Nombre del equipo no puede quedar vacio."); 
return false; 
} 
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_marca.Text)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("Marca del equipo no puede quedar vacio."); 
return false; 
} 
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_modelo.Text)) 
{ MessageBox.Show("Modelo del equipo no puede quedar vacio."); 
return false; 
} 
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_serie.Text)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("Serie del equipo no puede quedar vacio."); 
return false; 
} 
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_ubicacion.Text)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("Ubicación del equipo no puede quedar vacio."); return false; 
} 
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_empresa.Text)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("Falta ingresar información en el campo empresa que realiza el mantenimiento."); 
return false; 
}
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_persona.Text)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("Falta ingresar información en el campo persona que realiza el mantenimiento.");
 return false; 
} 
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("Falta ingresar información en el campo notas"); return false; 
} 
else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dtp_fmanten.Text)) 
{ 
MessageBox.Show("Debes seleccionar una fecha"); 
return false; 
}
```

Intente el siguiente código ... pero no hace nada , sólo me muestra el error por parte de la BD más no la validación gráfica.

```
//if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(chechar`introducir el código aquí`CHBox.Text)) 
//{ // MessageBox.Show("Debes seleccionar un opción de las 5 condiciones señaladas."); 
// return false; 
//} 
return true; 
//} 
//if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(checharCHBox.Text)) 
//{ 
// MessageBox.Show("Debes seleccionar un opción de las 5 condiciones señaladas."); 
// return false; 
//}
Dónde valido que el sistema no puede registrar si hace falta información [tengo código para validar que los text box no quede vacío] , pero no se como validar que el método *`introducir el código aquí`*CheckCondicion** (muestro código arriba) no quede vacío.
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta, está complicado leerla tal cual está. Aquí unas recomendaciones https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: Lei varias veces tu pregunta.. y no entiendo tu problema.. si el primer codigo valida checkbox como corresponde, y el segundo valida cualquier cosa, porque tratas de validar checkbox como si fueran campos de texto????

Comment: porque los check box devuelven un valor de texto para mi base de datos ... (nombre CheckCondicion()),,, el metodo checarValidez () tiene la función de validar que no quede vacía ninguna parte del form. ¡gracias!